# How to deploy AKS (Azure container service) in a VPN?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I want to deploy some kubernetes workloads, which are visible from some other VM's on Azure but not visible from the outside world.

For example: I might have a VM running a Zuul Gateway which for some routes I want to redirect to the K8s cluster, yet I don't want to allow people to directly access my K8s cluster.

Is it possible to place my AKS inside a VPN? If so, how should I achieve this?

Comment: You can use an NSG on the subnet that has your k8s agents. Police your traffic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to options, pointed out by @4c74356b41, you can run [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) on the cluster, and limit it to your internal server IP only

Answer (score 1):

So this isnt possible now (at least out of the box) due to the nature of AKS being a service with no VNet integration as of yet. You can try to hack around this, but it will probably not work really well as your agents need to talk to the master.

I see 2 options:

1. Use internal load balancers instead of public ones to expose your services
2. Use ACS which has vnet integration, but I'm not sure if you can apply 2 routes to the same vnet